# Mage2 : Arg 1 passed to Magento\Paypal\Model\Adminhtml\Express::isOrderAuthorizationAllowed() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.2.5, I am getting this error while view any order.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Paypal\Model\Adminhtml\Express::isOrderAuthorizationAllowed() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment, null given, called in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento_five\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Plugin\OrderCanInvoice.php on line 41 and defined in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento_five\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Adminhtml\Express.php:170 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento_five\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Plugin\OrderCanInvoice.php(41): Magento\Paypal\Model\Adminhtml\Express->isOrderAuthorizationAllowed(NULL) #1 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento_five\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Paypal\Plugin\OrderCanInvoice->afterCanInvoice(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor), false) #2 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento_five\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}() #3 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento_five\generated\code\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Inte in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento_five\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Adminhtml\Express.php on line 169

Can anybody help me into this.

Thank you

Comment: Anybody can help me into this please.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Magento version to 2.2.5.
Magento resolve above iisue on 2.2.5 version.